# How to use PKI Authentication to use the Opensearch Dashboards API?

Tags: kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards, opensearch-security-plugin

I am trying to use OpenSearch Dashboards API (Amazon Kibana fork) to add a search index.  I am using version 1.0 and have also setup the security plugin.  I have no issues using TLS PKI for interacting with OpenSearch (Elasticsearch).  However, whenever I try to interact with the OpenSearch Dashboard API with TLS PKI authentication, I get an error.  I am able to setup PKI within Dashboards to authenticate to OpenSearch without any issues.  Here is effectively the command on the shell using curl, but I am looking to use python when finished:

```
curl -X POST --cert MYCERT.crt --key MYKEY.key --cacert MY-CA-BUNDLE.crt https://HOSTNAME:5601/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/test-index -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'  { "attributes": {  "title": "test-index-*","timeFieldName": "@timestamp"  } }'
```

I get the following JSON message error back:

```
{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Authentication required"}
```

If I instead use the API with 'simple' username/password, the same command works:

```
curl -X POST -u USERNAME:PASSWORD https://HOSTNAME:5601/api/saved_objects/index-pattern/test-index -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'  { "attributes": {  "title": "test-index-*","timeFieldName": "@timestamp"  } }'
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to allow my ansible to issue a command to the API using PKI certificates, which I am looking to do so I can disable simple authentication.  Does anyone know what setting I am missing or if I am misusing the API?  I have studied the plugin documentation, but I can't find any item that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a simple query to Opensearch service like:

```
curl -XGET -k https://$(hostname):9200/ --key MYKEY.key --cert MYCERT.crt
```

If this one is not working, probably you need to check the certificates that are configured in opensearch.yml file.

Comment: Yes, Opensearch port 9200 works perfectly with the certificates.

Comment: Did you follow up this guide: https://opensearch.org/docs/security-plugin/configuration/client-auth/ ? I check in my Opensearch-dashboards, that in settings: http://localhost/app/security-dashboards-plugin#/auth option: clientcert_auth_domain is disabled